# Print a doubly linked list in reverse order?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, nodes, doubly-linked-list

My minimal reproducible example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
    struct NodeStruct *prev; //Create doubly linked list node
};

/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */
typedef struct {
    /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
    Node *head;
    Node *last;
} List;

List *list;

List *makeList();
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID);
static void printReverse(List *list);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Create an empty list for you to start.
    list = (List *)makeList();

    addRecord(list, 1);
    addRecord(list, 2);
    addRecord(list, 3);
    addRecord(list, 4);
    addRecord(list, 15);
    printReverse(list);
    return 0;
}

List *makeList() {
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID) {
    //Allocate memory for the node
    Node *new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

    //Add in data
    new->id = newID; 

    //New node has no next, yet
    new->next = NULL;

    Node **next_p = &list->head;
    while (*next_p) {
        next_p = &(*next_p)->next;
    }
    *next_p = new;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void printReverse(List *list) {
    Node **tail = &list->last;
    printf("LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:\n");

    //Traversing until tail end of linked list
    while (*tail) {
        printf("Item ID: %d\n", (*tail)->id);
        tail = &(*tail)->prev;
    }
}
```

Input:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 15

Expected output:

> 15 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

Actual output:

> segmentation fault

---

EDIT: Set the `prev` node in the linked list:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
    struct NodeStruct *prev; //Create doubly linked list node
};

/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */
typedef struct {
    /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
    Node *head;
    Node *last;
} List;

List *list;

List *makeList();
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID);
static void printReverse(List *list);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Create an empty list for you to start.
    list = (List *)makeList();

    addRecord(list, 1);
    addRecord(list, 2);
    addRecord(list, 3);
    addRecord(list, 4);
    addRecord(list, 15);
    printReverse(list);
    return 0;
}

List *makeList() {
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID) {
    //Allocate memory for the node
    Node *new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

    //Add in data
    new->id = newID; 
    new->prev = NULL;

    //New node has no next, yet
    new->next = NULL;

    Node **next_p = &list->head;
    while (*next_p) {
        next_p = &(*next_p)->next;
    }
    *next_p = new;
    list->last = new;
    new->prev = *next_p;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void printReverse(List *list) {
    Node **tail = &list->last;
    printf("LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:\n");

    //Traversing until tail end of linked list
    while (*tail) {
        printf("Item ID: %d\n", (*tail)->id);
        tail = &(*tail)->prev;
    }
}
```

With this edit made to `addRecord`, I keep getting an infinite loop that prints `Item ID: 15` over and over again.

Comment: shouldn't it be tail = &(*tail)->prev? And why are you using pointers to pointers?Regardless, please provide a reproducible example, it can be that you are not setting to NULL some pointers or some other issue.

Comment: I'm working on getting a minimal reproducible example up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You add (append to be exact, you add it to end) your first node, with a value of 1, and you set `head` to it. But what about `last`? Isn't the last node also the first node in your list? Yes it is! Moreover, you set the `next` pointer to `NULL`, correct... But what about the `prev` pointer? Shouldn't it be set to `NULL` too, since their so no previous node? Yes again.

2) `list` does not need to be global, and to be honest, it shouldn't be.

3) When you do:

```
*next_p = new;
new->prev = *next_p;
```

then you say that the previous node of the newly appended node is the new node. It should be the last, which we know apriori, so we can do:

```
new->prev = list->last;
```

just after constructing the node.

4) Furthermore, when you create the empty list, the status should be that both head and last pointers are set to NULL.

5) Finally, you could simplify your print function to not use a double pointer, but just a pointer.

Putting everything together, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
    struct NodeStruct *prev; //Create doubly linked list node
};

/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */
typedef struct {
  /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
  Node *head;
  Node *last;
} List;

List *makeList();
static void *addRecordAtEnd(List *list, int newID);
void print(List *list);
void printReverse(List *list);

int main() 
{
  // Create an empty list for you to start.
  List* list = makeList();

  addRecordAtEnd(list, 1);
  addRecordAtEnd(list, 2);
  addRecordAtEnd(list, 3);
  addRecordAtEnd(list, 4);
  addRecordAtEnd(list, 15);
  print(list);
  printReverse(list);
  return 0;
}

List *makeList()
{
  List *list = malloc( sizeof( List ) );
  if(list != NULL)
  {
    list->head = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
  }
  return list;
}

static void *addRecordAtEnd(List *list, int newID) 
{
  //Allocate memory for the node
  Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

  //Add in data
  new->id = newID; 

  new->prev = list->last;
  new->next = NULL;

  list->last = new;

  // if list is empty
  if(!list->head)
  {
    list->head = new;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  Node **next_p = &list->head;
  while (*next_p) {
    next_p = &(*next_p)->next;
  }
  *next_p = new;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void print(List *list)
{
  Node *current_node = list->head;
  while (current_node) {
    printf("Item ID: %d\n", current_node->id);
    current_node = current_node->next;
  }
}

void printReverse(List *list)
{
  Node *current_node = list->last;
  printf("LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:\n");

  //Traversing until tail end of linked list
  while (current_node) {
    printf("Item ID: %d\n", current_node->id);
    current_node = current_node->prev;
  }
}
```

Output (to also check that the next pointers are correctly set):

```
Item ID: 1
Item ID: 2
Item ID: 3
Item ID: 4
Item ID: 15
LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:
Item ID: 15
Item ID: 4
Item ID: 3
Item ID: 2
Item ID: 1
```

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: I just did this, and my only output seems to be `LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:`, and none of my data is printing. I am possibly thinking there is something wrong with how my node and list are constructed?

Comment: @PomegranateSociety definitely. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a minimal reproducible example, so that we can see.. :)

Comment: Hi there! I just posted one, I am working through debugging it now!

Comment: Hi again gmsamaras, I made another edit to my code. Could you give me feedback? Also, I used the cast with malloc simply because that is how I was taught to do with linked list creations!

Comment: Hey @PomegranateSociety, nice attempt, and nice MCVE! I updated my answer with the solution, hope you like it!

Comment: Why iterate to locate the last node? `list->last` already points to it. New elements can be appended to a doubly links list in constant time.

Comment: `printList()` and `printReverse()`  should **not** modify the list! Use a local variable instead of `list->head` or `list->last` to iterate from the end. These functions only work once and make the list unusable.

Comment: @chqrlie good catch, *fixed*! You don't iterate the list to locate the last node! It just that the OP put it there I think, but I agree, it can be moved.. ;)

Comment: Another question: why do you return `list` from `addRecordAtEnd()`? The OP had this function return a success indicator. `list` is not reallocated.

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie for helping me improving my solution, I rolledback to OP's approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in function `addRecord()`: `new->prev = *next_p;`

`next_p` is not a pointer to the last node, it is a pointer to the `next` member of the last node. In this particular case, `*next_p` has been set to `new` just before.

It is simpler to not use the double pointer trick for doubly linked lists and just special case the empty list:

```c
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID) {
    //Allocate memory for the node
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

    if (new_node == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    //Add in data
    new_node->id = newID; 
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        list->head = new_node;
    } else {
        new_node->prev = list->last;
        list->last->next = new_node;
    }
    list->last = new_node;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Similarly, the print function can be written without a double pointer:

```c
static void printReverse(List *list) {
    // Traversing until tail end of linked list
    printf("LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:\n");
    for (Node *node = list->last; node; node = node->prev) {
        printf("Item ID: %d\n", node->id);
    }
}
```

Note that the initialization function must initialize `last` too for `printReverse` to handle empty lists correctly:

```c
List *makeList() {
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list != NULL) {
        list->head = list->last = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer as well, +1 for the check of whether the list is NULL or not in the `makeList()`.